# Encrypting application.yml file

Tags: spring, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I want to encrypt application.yml with aes256 encryption algorithm so that if someone want to decrypt it,they need a unique key.
application.yml

```
security:
 TEST:
  Host:yummy.com
  Port:9000
  Password:£-+:_#642
  Secure:true
 DEV:
  Host:ZIM.com
  Port:9001
  Password:3678&££
  Secure:true
```

//Configuration class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="security")
public class SecurityProperties implements Serializable{

TESTPrpperties;
DEVProperties;
//getter and setter
public static class TESTProperties{

  Host;
  Port;
  Password;
  Secure;
//getter and setter
}
public static class DEVProperties{

  Host;
  Port;
  Password;
  Secure;
//getter and setter
}

}
```

Now we have encryption class

```
    @Qualifier
    private SecurityProperties devconfig;
    public String encryptObj() {

        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
             KeyGenerator    gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
             gen.init(256);
             SecretKey sKey = gen.generateKey();
              Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
              c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,sKey);
              SealedObject so = new SealedObject(devconfig,c);
              ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
              oos.writeObject(so);
              oos.flush();
              System.out.println("SealedObject was written to Object file");
              } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
              }

        return null;
```

Running application successfully I am testing in postman but i am not getting application.yml data in encrypted in postman and i want to return specific encrypted data like for under TESTProperties data and DEVProperties data separetly in encrypted form.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell why `i am not getting any data returned`. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @gusto2,I have modified above code.

Comment: You plan to hard-code "key" into source code or place it into another yaml file so you would be able to decrypt yaml file during application startup, right? So you are placing confidential information into safe, write down pincode for the lock on sticker and stick it to the safe door near the lock. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Maxim Sagaydachny,you got it and key would be store in another secure file.

Comment: And app will be able to access this another secure file at startup as well? So you will place sticker with pincode under the safe instead of sticking it to the door?

Comment: @Maxim Sagaydachny,yes.can u solve my problems.

Comment: here is good example on how to encrypt and decrypt data https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571774/12396017 . But what you are doing is security through obscurity and such solutions are never secure. So my answer to your question would be - do not store encrypted data along with the key. Your data is not protected unless you have method to protect the key.

Comment: @Maxim Sagaydachny, as u can see that I want to encrypt above application.yml file which I have read data through securityproperties class then trying to encrypt that class.and in your example it is encrypting string value.